# Symbian: How correctly cancel long async socket operation

Tags: sockets, symbian

I have one simple question that is care me. It's about Sockets API in Symbian.

How should I close the current long async operation?
For example, if I doing the operation like `CSecureSocket::StartClientHandshake` for GPRS it's quite long operation. If I want to close my app,I should call `Cancel()` that is sync op. and I'm waiting about 3 minutes while the `CSecureSocket::StartClientHandshake` will be completed.

It's not that I want. Instead I calls `CSecureSocket::Close()`. It broke my handshake process, closed the socket. But the next time I get a callback `MyClass::Run` with error `Canceled`. It's normal if I don't close my app. But it's a mistake if I delete my `MyClass`.

If I want to delete `MyClass`, the `~MyClass` should call the `Cancel()` but it will keep me waiting about 3 minutes.

And it's my question: how should I close the long async operation ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK calling Close should internally call Cancel for all running operations. Thats why you get this Canceled notification. So when deleting your MyClass then also call Close, not Cancel.